# How to check if certain row in textarea is empty?

Tags: javascript, textarea, row

How to check if certain row in textarea is empty with javascript?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).bind('keydown',function (e) {

if(e.which==13) {
function isRowEmpty( idOfTextArea , row ){

  return $("#" + idOfTextArea )[0].value.split("\n")[row-1] == "";

}
alert(isRowEmpty("txtarr",3));

    }
});
</script>
<textarea id="txtarr" rows="30" ></textarea>
```

But it returns always false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Assumes you use jQuery or equivalent
function isRowEmpty( idOfTextArea , row ){

  return $("#" + idOfTextArea )[0].value.split("\n")[row-1] == "";

}
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).bind('keydown',function (e) {

if(e.which==13) {
function isRowEmpty( idOfTextArea , row ){

  return $("#" + idOfTextArea )[0].value.split("\n")[row-1] == "";

}
alert(isRowEmpty("txtarr",3));
 
 }
});
</script>
<textarea id="txtarr" rows="30" ></textarea>

But it returns always false?

Comment: .toString(); gives me 
---
fffffffffffffffffsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Answer (score 1):

use `string.split("\n", limit)`, where string is the textarea value.

Then, use your standard FOR loop, and do something like `if (list[i].match("/(\s)/"))` to check for a line that is only whitespace.

Comment: If I want to check whether the last row is empty?

Comment: If for certain row, the i should be predefined.

Comment: According to the example, for last row:
var list = string.split(separator, limit);
if(list[list.length-1] == ""){
// to do...
}
 should do the trick

Comment: What to write on the seprator ,limit place?
seprator - / ? But limit?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that lines are separated by "\n"

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function rows() {
var lines;
var TA=document.form1.textarea1.value;
if(document.all) { // IE
lines=TA.split("\r\n");
}
else { //Mozilla
lines=TA.split("\n");
}
for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
    if (lines[i].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '').length == 0) {
        alert('Line ' + i + ' is empty')
    }
}
}
//-->
</script>
```